# Serving an svg within JSON using NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, svg

I have a small reactJS app that rendered objects with svg in them:

```
import { ReactComponent as F01 } from "./F01.svg";

export const toRender = {
  title:"Render this",
  text:"Test",
  SVGFile: F01
}
```

I would import this into a component and render it as a component `<SVGFile />`. All was working 100%.

---

Now the app got bigger and it became inefficient to store the objects in the frontend. I am trying to send the object from an ExpressJS server. I get an error importing the SVG file.

Here is the route I am using, which works well without SVG files:

```
import {testObject} from "./testObject";

export const getTestObject= {
  path: "/api/render",
  method: "get",
  handler: (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    return res.json(testObject);
  },
};
```

And here is the testObject I am sending:

```
import { F01 } from "./F01.svg";

export const testObject = {
  title:"Render this",
  text:"Test",
  SVGFile: F01
}
```

But I get an error right after starting tsnode:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (D:\desktop\codebases\360ExamPrep\backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1608:43)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> ....
```

I am not using webpack on the backend.
I tried using `const F01 = require('./F01.svg)` but that did not help.
Any help is highly appreciated